# Combine jquery with php ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having a problem. I'm creating a dynamic table with jquery (the user insert a value and then it creates the table). Now in the Table I have a Select tab with pre-defined values that are coming from a table in my database (mysql).

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit").click(function(e) {

       $("#Table").empty();
       e.preventDefault();

       if($("#NumOfLevels").val() >0)
        {
            var size = $("#NumOfLevels").val();
            var str='';
            str+='<table align="center" width="694" border="0" cellspacing="3"  cellpadding="0">';
            str+='<tr><th style="width:auto" scope="col">level </th><th width="107">score</th><th width="58">game file</th><th width="80">catalog</th><th width="93">start date</th><th width="85">end date/th></tr>';


            for(var i = 0; i< size ; i++)
            {

              str+='<tr><td id="stage'+i+'" style="width:auto">level  '+(i+1)+'</td><td><span id="sprytextfield4"><input type="text"    name="Score" id="Score"/>';
              str+='<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>';
              str+='<td><input type="file" name="gameFile" id="gameFile" /></td>';
              str+='<td><select multiple="multiple" name="CatlogLink" id="CatlogLink">';

               **Here Is Where I Need To Enter My PHP Function**
               str+='</select></td>';
               str+='<td><input type="text" class="date" id="datepicker" ></td>';
               str+='<td><input type="text" class="date" id="datepicker2" "></td>';
               //str.find('input').datepicker();
            }

            //str+='</tr></table>';

            $("#Table").append(str);
            var btn = '';
            btn+='<tr><td width="192" colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" value="submit"/></td>';
            btn+='<td width="309" colspan="4" align="center"><input type="reset" name="reset" id="Clear" value="clear" /></td></tr></tr></table>';
            $("#Table tr:last").after(btn);


        }
        $(".date").click(function() {
            $( ".date" ).datepicker();
            $( ".date" ).datepicker();
         });
    });
});
```

and my question is how to get the php code that generates the option list to integarte with my javascript code.

- My Php Function only retrieve some values (Names) I don't send to the function any data.

Regards,
Yotam.

Comment: the code looks incomplete `#Table` where is this id is defined. What is `myCall`

Comment: You need to do your ajax request _before_ constructing your table. Fetch the data, store it in a JS array, then iterate this array when constructing your table.

Comment: I'll correct it thank you (It's a mistake).